# Help me get Scala source blocks working in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, debugging

**UPDATE:** This issue was fixed for me by changing my version of scala from scala 3 to 2.13, as recommended by NickD in the comments below.
**END UPDATE**

When I attempt to evaluate Scala source blocks in org mode, I get a strange output. For instance:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scala
  def hello: Unit = println("hello")
  hello
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Ignoring spurious arguments: /var/folders/_q/ykjmqmwd3m38l5qqj3j1g9wh0000gn/T/babel-S0YTp0/scala-OKojWy
: Welcome to Scala 3.3.0 (20.0.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
: Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
: 
: scala>
```

It looks like the output of the scala repl. Here is my `ob-scala.el` file:

```lisp
;; - Scala language :: http://www.scala-lang.org/
;; - Scala major mode :: Can be installed from Scala sources
;;  https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/tool-support/src/emacs/scala-mode.el

;;; Code:
(require 'ob)
(require 'ob-ref)
(require 'ob-comint)
(require 'ob-eval)
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))

(defvar org-babel-tangle-lang-exts) ;; Autoloaded
(add-to-list 'org-babel-tangle-lang-exts '("scala" . "scala"))
(defvar org-babel-default-header-args:scala '())
(defvar org-babel-scala-command "scala"
  "Name of the command to use for executing Scala code.")

(defun org-babel-execute:scala (body params)
  "Execute a block of Scala code with org-babel.  This function is
called by `org-babel-execute-src-block'"
  (message "executing Scala source code block")
  (let* ((processed-params (org-babel-process-params params))
         (session (org-babel-scala-initiate-session (nth 0 processed-params)))
         (vars (nth 1 processed-params))
         (result-params (nth 2 processed-params))
         (result-type (cdr (assoc :result-type params)))
         (full-body (org-babel-expand-body:generic
                     body params))
         (result (org-babel-scala-evaluate
                  session full-body result-type result-params)))

    (org-babel-reassemble-table
     result
     (org-babel-pick-name
      (cdr (assoc :colname-names params)) (cdr (assoc :colnames params)))
     (org-babel-pick-name
      (cdr (assoc :rowname-names params)) (cdr (assoc :rownames params))))))


(defun org-babel-scala-table-or-string (results)
  "Convert RESULTS into an appropriate elisp value.
If RESULTS look like a table, then convert them into an
Emacs-lisp table, otherwise return the results as a string."
  (org-babel-script-escape results))


(defvar org-babel-scala-wrapper-method

"var str_result :String = null;

Console.withOut(new java.io.OutputStream() {def write(b: Int){
}}) {
  str_result = {
%s
  }.toString
}

print(str_result)
")


(defun org-babel-scala-evaluate
  (session body &optional result-type result-params)
  "Evaluate BODY in external Scala process.
If RESULT-TYPE equals 'output then return standard output as a string.
If RESULT-TYPE equals 'value then return the value of the last statement
in BODY as elisp."
  (when session (error "Sessions are not (yet) supported for Scala"))
  (case result-type
    (output
     (let ((src-file (org-babel-temp-file "scala-")))
       (progn (with-temp-file src-file (insert body))
              (org-babel-eval
               (concat org-babel-scala-command " " src-file) ""))))
    (value
     (let* ((src-file (org-babel-temp-file "scala-"))
            (wrapper (format org-babel-scala-wrapper-method body)))
       (with-temp-file src-file (insert wrapper))
       ((lambda (raw)
          (if (member "code" result-params)
              raw
            (org-babel-scala-table-or-string raw)))
        (org-babel-eval
         (concat org-babel-scala-command " " src-file) ""))))))


(defun org-babel-prep-session:scala (session params)
  "Prepare SESSION according to the header arguments specified in PARAMS."
  (error "Sessions are not (yet) supported for Scala"))

(defun org-babel-scala-initiate-session (&optional session)
  "If there is not a current inferior-process-buffer in SESSION
then create.  Return the initialized session.  Sessions are not
supported in Scala."
  nil)

(provide 'ob-scala)



;;; ob-scala.el ends here
```

Here is a relavent portion of my emacs config:

```lisp
;; SCALA Support
;; Add melpa to your packages repositories
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

;; Install use-package if not already installed
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)

;; Enable defer and ensure by default for use-package
;; Keep auto-save/backup files separate from source code:  https://github.com/scalameta/metals/issues/1027
(setq use-package-always-defer t
      use-package-always-ensure t
      backup-directory-alist `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory))
      auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))

;; Enable scala-mode for highlighting, indentation and motion commands
(use-package scala-mode
  :interpreter ("scala" . scala-mode))
(use-package scala-mode
  :mode "\\.s\\(cala\\|bt\\)$"
  :config
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/lisp/ob-scala.el"))

;; Enable sbt mode for executing sbt commands
(use-package sbt-mode
  :commands sbt-start sbt-command
  :config
  ;; WORKAROUND: https://github.com/ensime/emacs-sbt-mode/issues/31
  ;; allows using SPACE when in the minibuffer
  (substitute-key-definition
   'minibuffer-complete-word
   'self-insert-command
   minibuffer-local-completion-map)
   ;; sbt-supershell kills sbt-mode:  https://github.com/hvesalai/emacs-sbt-mode/issues/152
   (setq sbt:program-options '("-Dsbt.supershell=false")))

;; Enable nice rendering of diagnostics like compile errors.
;; (use-package flycheck
;;   :init (global-flycheck-mode))

(use-package lsp-mode
  ;; Optional - enable lsp-mode automatically in scala files
  ;; You could also swap out lsp for lsp-deffered in order to defer loading
  :hook  (scala-mode . lsp)
         (lsp-mode . lsp-lens-mode)
  :config
  ;; Uncomment following section if you would like to tune lsp-mode performance according to
  ;; https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/
  ;; (setq gc-cons-threshold 100000000) ;; 100mb
  ;; (setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ;; 1mb
  ;; (setq lsp-idle-delay 0.500)
  ;; (setq lsp-log-io nil)
  ;; (setq lsp-completion-provider :capf)
  (setq lsp-prefer-flymake nil)
  ;; Makes LSP shutdown the metals server when all buffers in the project are closed.
  ;; https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-keep-workspace-alive
  (setq lsp-keep-workspace-alive nil))

;; Add metals backend for lsp-mode
(use-package lsp-metals)

;; Enable nice rendering of documentation on hover
;;   Warning: on some systems this package can reduce your emacs responsiveness significally.
;;   (See: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/)
;;   In that case you have to not only disable this but also remove from the packages since
;;   lsp-mode can activate it automatically.
(use-package lsp-ui)

;; lsp-mode supports snippets, but in order for them to work you need to use yasnippet
;; If you don't want to use snippets set lsp-enable-snippet to nil in your lsp-mode settings
;; to avoid odd behavior with snippets and indentation
(use-package yasnippet)

;; Use company-capf as a completion provider.
;;
;; To Company-lsp users:
;;   Company-lsp is no longer maintained and has been removed from MELPA.
;;   Please migrate to company-capf.
(use-package company
  :hook (scala-mode . company-mode)
  :config
  (setq lsp-completion-provider :capf))

;; Posframe is a pop-up tool that must be manually installed for dap-mode
(use-package posframe)

;; Use the Debug Adapter Protocol for running tests and debugging
(use-package dap-mode
  :hook
  (lsp-mode . dap-mode)
  (lsp-mode . dap-ui-mode))

;; ORG SRC BLOCKS
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '(
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (python . t)
   (ruby . t)
   (js . t)
   (C . t)
   (wolfram . t)
   (octave . t)
   (latex . t)
   (lisp . t)
   (dot . t)
   (scala . t)
   ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala babel implementation seems similar to the Python babel implementation where `:results value` (the default) and `:results output` are treated differently. For the first case, your program is wrapped in a Java wrapper (see `org-babel-scala-wrapper-method`).

OTOH, with `:results output`, there is no wrapper and the results are whatever your program prints out. So try:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC scala :results output
  def hello: Unit = println("hello")
  hello
#+END_SRC
```

EDIT: The above is necessary but not sufficient. The OP still had a problem even after adding the `:results output` header arg. I suggested that it might be a version problem: I was testing with Scala 2.13.10, but the OP was running Scala 3.3.0. Downgrading to 2.13 made it work.

Of course, that means that `ob-scala.el` does not work with the new version of Scala and will need work, but I'm not sure whether it is supported at all, so I'm not sure where the bug report should be sent. I'll try to find out and update this answer with that information.

Comment: I tried it but got the same result:
`#+BEGIN_SRC scala :results output
  def hello: Unit = println("hello")
  hello
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Ignoring spurious arguments: /var/folders/_q/ykjmqmwd3m38l5qqj3j1g9wh0000gn/T/babel-S0YTp0/scala-bSQRwW
: Welcome to Scala 3.3.0 (20.0.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
: Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
: 
: scala>`

Comment: All I can say is that it works for me, so there is probably something wrong with your setup. Check the contents of `/var/folders/_q/ykjmqmwd3m38l5qqj3j1g9wh0000gn/T/babel-S0YTp0/scala-bSQRwW`. It should just have your program in it. If worse comes to worst, instument `org-babel-scala-evaluate` with `edebug` and step through it to figure out where it goes off the cliff.

Comment: It  may be a version problem: `scala --version` shows `Scala code runner version 2.13.10 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.` in my case.

Comment: Changing my version of Scala to 2.13 made it work. I don't know if I'm supposed to click the checkmark for your answer given the solution was in the comments.

Comment: Answer updated.